# sublime text 2: check if file is up to date or was changed

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext2

How can I make sublime text 2 keep my files up to date if multiple people are making changes to the same file from different computers?

If someone makes a change to `fileName.txt` while I am editing the same file, I don't want to overwrite their changes when I save.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for a proper source control system, not a text editor.

Comment: I do use git on a few projects, but when someone else pushes their changes, my text editor doesn't get updated until I close and reopen the file.

Comment: push shouldn't affect your file, but pull will.  When my file changes externally the sublime text editor seems to update, although not always.